# Writing superficial wrappers for functions [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab

I have a function in Matlab:

```
function [runs,balls]=batting(form,team_flag,weather_flag)
```

`form` is a `1x13` array of doubles. The flags are just boolean. `runs,balls` are just scalars. The function above does some complex mathematical simulation to arrive at its output values. Now i write a wrapper :

```
function [runs,balls]=wrapper1(form)
[runs,balls]=batting(form,false,false);
```

Then I write another wrapper:

```
function runs_vector=wrapper2(form_vector)
for i=1:size(form_vector,1)
    form_cell{i}=form_vector(i,:);
end
runs_vector=cellfun(@wrapper1, form_cell)';
```

It must be evident as to what i am trying to achieve. I am trying to exploit the behavior of `cellfun` for my custom-defined function `batting`. The flag arguments need to be set to false here but in general they are varied in the project of which this is part of. So i could not disappear the flag inputs to the `batting` function without writing an intermediate wrapper,i.e. `wrapper1`. My question is if there is a less ugly or more smart way of doing this?

Comment: You should modify `batting`, such that it takes a `n x 13` matrix as input, which makes both wrappers obsolete.

Comment: But the thing is that the complex mathematical simulation is the function batting which takes a 1x13 vector. Generalizing it for nx13 matrix would require to run a for loop `n` times in the batting function. Rather i have done so using the wrappers. And this seems more elegant than the for loop method. I want to keep the complex math sim as a separate blackbox which i don't want to peep into let alone modify!

Comment: Note that `cellfun` (and all the *funs) is slower than the explicit loop in almost all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eliminate `wrapper1` by creating an anonymous function that reduces `batting` to two arguments:

```
runs_vector = cellfun(@(form) batting(form, false, false), form_cell)';
```

In addition, the loop can be replaced by [`num2cell`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) like so:

```
form_cell = num2cell(form_vector, 2);
```

Combining these two gives us

```
function runs_vector = wrapper2(form_vector)
form_cell = num2cell(form_vector, 2);
runs_vector = cellfun(@(form) batting(form, false, false), form_cell)';
```